# Add each element of the array separately to the DIALOG command as a menu

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, dialog

I need to add each element of the array to the Dialog menu. The problem is that with the command $ {array [@]} the dialog is recognizing each word as an element. Look:

**First attempt: Adding element with spaces**

```sh
list=('Google Chrome' 'Brackets' 'Visual Studio') # my list
declare -a dia # dialog array

for index in ${!list[@]}; do # for each index in the list
    dia[${#dia[@]}]=$index # add index
    dia[${#dia[@]}]=${list[$index]} #add element
done

dialog --menu "MENU" 0 0 0 $(echo ${dia[@]})

# Format: dialog --menu "TITLE" 0 0 0 'Index1' 'Element1' 'Index2' 'Element2'...

# dia[0] = 0
# dia[1] = 'Google Chrome' 
# dia[1] = 1 
# dia[2] = 'Brackets'...
```

[PRINT: first attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F09MJ.png)

I did this to avoid processing each word, with the return of $ {list [@]} separating word by word, obtaining a sequence of number and string.

**Second attempt: Replace ' ' with '-'**

```sh
for index in ${!list[@]}; do
    dgl[${#dgl[@]}]=$index 
    dgl[${#dgl[@]}]=${list[$index]/' '/'-'}
done
```

[PRINT: Second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGIpP.png)

**What I think is happening**

I believe that when passing the elements of the array to the DIALOG command it considers spaces ("Google Chrome", for example). Is there a way for me to show this with spaces?

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Thanks, but... I added the  #!/Bin/bash and based on shellcheck.net I added double quotes in ${!list[@]} and $(echo ${dia[@]}). The result was an error saying that only one element was inserted, as it recognized $ (echo $ {day [@]}) as a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made all necessary changes to your code so it now works as expected.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

list=('Google Chrome' 'Brackets' 'Visual Studio') # my list
declare -a dia=()                                 # dialog array

for index in "${!list[@]}"; do # for each index in the list
  dia+=("$index" "${list[index]}")
done

choice=$(
  dialog --menu "MENU" 0 0 0 "${dia[@]}" \
    3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- # Swap stdout with stderr to capture returned dialog text
)
dialog_rc=$? # Save the dialog return code

clear # restore terminal background and clear

case $dialog_rc in
  0)
    printf 'Your choice was: %s\n' "${list[choice]}"
    ;;
  1)
    echo 'Cancelled menu'
    ;;
  255)
    echo 'Closed menu without choice'
    ;;
  *)
    printf 'Unknown return code from dialog: %d\n' $dialog_rc >&2
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning ... I didn't know +=, how amazing! I also have to understand what this 3> is. I came from javascript and I'm creating my first application like this. It is very different. Thank you very much for your reply! Yea!

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand these descriptors. I still don't understand how you inserted it into choice. I don't think I was born for shell script anyway (:D)
I would have to see everything that happens to these descriptors inside to get a better understanding.

Comment: @HugoRodrigues `3>&1` Redirect Descriptor 3 (unused for now) to stdoutput (descriptor 1). `1>&2` Redirect command stdoutput to Stderror (descriptor 2). `2>&3` Redirect stderror to Descriptor 3. `3>&-` Close descriptor 3. It is like you need to swap 2 cars between 2 parking lots using a 3rd parking lot: Car1 in lot1 go to lot 3, car2 in lot2 go to lot 1, car1 in lot3 go to lot2, now unused lot3 can be closed.